# Relational Model vs EAV

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-attribute-value

Database beginner here.

I've been researching column-store model for a while, I came up to [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5478926&tag=1). It basically proposes special column-store model to sparse and huge clinical data for fast searching.

I generally understand what the paper proposes but some thoughts on relational model and EAV model confused me. The paper postulates that relational model cannot be even thought to use for clinical data and compares performances of EAV and column-store model.

> EAV can represent high dimensional data, which cannot be modeled by relational model because existing RDBMS only support a limited number of columns.

As I understand from [this question](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_some_examples_of_high-dimensional_data) and its first answer, clinical data is high-dimensional (as expected) but

Why classical normalization is not used and EAV is used for that?

Relational model would be:

```
Person: Id, Name, Surname, DateOfBirth, ...
Measurement: Id, Name, Desc, ...
PersonMeasurement: Id, PersonId, MeasurementId, Result, Date
```

Comment: The limits of existing RDBMS don't prevent us from modeling high-dimensional data using the relational model, in the same way the limits of an abacus don't prevent us from representing large numbers algebraically.  Existing RDBMS don't even faithfully implement the relational model.

Comment: Note that your PersonMeasurement table is an EAV model and not a relational data model.  In particular, the domain of the Result column depends on the value of the MeasurmentId.  A relational data model would organize the measurements as first-order predicates, e.g. `Weight (PersonId PK, Date PK, Kilograms)`, `BloodPressure (PersonId PK, Date PK, Systolic, Diastolic)` and so on.

Comment: It is very clear to me now, thanks. One more question though. How do one can represent Weight and BloodPressure as true relational model in todays RDBMS?

Comment: My previous comment already showed how to do it - make a separate table for each distinct normalized predicate.

Comment: I refuse to believe that for a while :)

Comment: Combining predicates into one or a few tables with nullable columns for measurements can also be viewed as relational, though the use of nulls in a "true relational model" is contentious.

Comment: The quote is nonsense, it does not reflect an understanding of the relational model. A row in a table with n columns is a point in an n-dimensional space. Anyway the relational model is about how users conceive of data, not implemenation. PS Please quote with attribution what is relevant in the linked answer. Also "first answer"--oldest? most recent? most popular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...because existing RDBMS only support a limited number of columns.

This depends on the meaning given to the term "limited": a typical modern relational database has a number of columns that exceeds 1000. Here is a table with the maximum number of columns of some of the most common RDBMS:

```
PostgresQL: 250 - 1600 depending on column types
MySQL: upto 4096, depending on row size
Oracle: 1000
IBM DB2: 1012
Mycrosoft SQL Server: 1024 - 30000
Sybase: 45000
```

In your second link there is the following statement:

> Data on health status of patients can be high-dimensional (100+ measured/recorded parameters from blood analysis, immune system status, genetic background, nutrition, alcohol- tobacco- drug-consuption, operations, treatments, diagnosed diseases, ...)

*Edited*

So, if the number of columns is in the order of the hundreds, I think that the single table approach is adequate to represent clinical data, and, as you can see from many questions on StackOverflow, more efficient and simple to query  than the EAV model.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the main problem is that if one normalizes tables, it is nothing to do with adding too many columns. We'll add new measurement types to Measurement table and new measurements to PersonMeasurement table. This goes to three table and reasonable amount of column. I do not understand why anyone creates a new column for every measurement type?

Comment: Actually the relational schema that you propose is a kind of EAV schema, but note that the alternative schema with a single table is not a non-normalized schema! And you can always add new columns to a table in a RDBMS. So, I think that the choice between the two schemas depends on how many attributes there are and how frequently new measurements are added to the database.

Comment: Why is alternative schema with a single table not non-normalized? Because measurements are kind of person info?

Comment: Yes. Measurements are attributes of person. The single table approach is a normalized one since all the columns depends on the primary key of persons.

Comment: Yes, I should have thought this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dewe, note that a single table approach is ok if you want to keep the current measures of a certain patient. If you want to keep the history of all the measures of a patient you should use the three tables approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106321/discussion-between-dewe-and-renzo).